# Changing the configuration of TF6250-Modbus-TCP when used in TwinCAT/BSD

Tags: bsd, modbus-tcp, twincat

I have a device running TwinCAT/BSD.

Following [section 5 the manual for TwinCAT/BSD](https://download.beckhoff.com/download/Document/ipc/embedded-pc/embedded-pc-cx/TwinCAT_BSD_en.pdf) I have successfully managed to install the TF6250 package. After updating the firewall rules I have confirmed that I am able connect and issue modbus tcp requests successfully using the Default Configuration [from section 4.3 of the TF6250 manual](https://download.beckhoff.com/download/Document/automation/twincat3/TF6250_TC3_Modbus_TCP_EN.pdf).

My project requires mapping that is different from the default (i.e to the %Q registers rather than %M). Normally (when not not using TwinCAT/BSD) I would be able to edit my mapping via the Modbus TCP Configurator, but there does not appear to be an equivalent tool contained in the package for TwinCAT/BSD.

I have tried copying the mapping files that I would have created in the configurator into the Server directory with no luck. Are you able to tell me how my mapping can be updated in the TwinCAT/BSD environment?

If relevant:

- TwinCAT Build: 3.1.4024.19
- TC/BSD: 12.2.9.1,2
- TF6250-Modbus-TCP: 2.0.1.0_1
- pkg repo: https://tcbsd.beckhoff.com/TCBSD/12/stable/packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with Beckhoff support who told that TF6250 expects the xml file with the configuration here: /usr/local/etc/TwinCAT/Functions/TF6250-Modbus-TCP/TcModbusSrv.xml

I tested this and it appears to work so all you need to do;

- Create the mapping file as per normal (e.g using the windows tool) and copy the file there.
- Reboot the device to load the configuration from the file.